# Dovecot Virtual Mailboxes issue. Can't create virtual mailboxes

Tags: dovecot

I'm trying to setup virtual mailboxes. Not virtual user accounts, but rather virtual folders IN the user account.

This is to achieve better management of incoming mail. Somewhat like Gmail does with it's labels.

This is supposed to be super [easy to enable](http://wiki.dovecot.org/Plugins/Virtual).  Just add  a namespace

```
namespace virtual {
  prefix = virtual.
  separator = .
  location = virtual:~/Maildir/virtual:LAYOUT=maildir++
}
```

then add the mailbox to the namespace

```
namespace virtual {
  mailbox "All mail" {
    special_use = \All
    auto = subscribe
    comment = All my messages
  }
}
```

and enabling the virtual plugin `mail_plugins = $mail_plugins virtual`

This is all fine but I get an error in the logs

`Error: Failed to autocreate mailbox virtual.All Mail: Can't create virtual mailboxes`

I don't understand why and can't find anything on that issue.

My guess would be a permission issue, but then again the `virtual` directory located at `~/Maildir/virtual` is created but it's the `~/Maildir/virtual.All mail` that seems to be having issues.

If it's a permission thing, where should I check? What should I be modifying in the configuration?

Thanks for your help

**EDIT**

Ok, I still need help understanding this. But I managed to get something going on thanks to [this mailing list message](http://dovecot.org/pipermail/dovecot/2011-September/131275.html)

It seems that even if the `LAYOUT` is `maildir++` you need to structure your virtual folders under `virtual/All`, `virtual/Work` etc., structure ( which is the default `LAYOUT=fs` for virtual folders. BUT, you have to reference them with the `.` notation which is `maildir++` structure throughout the configuration files.

Either I don't understand something or this is a bug.

Another weird behaviour, is that I can't seem to get anything else than `virtual:~/Maildir/virtual` to work.  Meaning if I want to name the virtual folder something else than `virtual` it doesn't seem to be picked up by the mail client.

<del>Finally, I was under the impression that if you putted `list = children` and `hidden = true` under your namespace, you wouldn't see the actual `virtual` folder as a parent in your mail client, but only the child virtual folders.</del>  Ok, I guess that rereading the docs, if you hide the namespace, no child will be listed. But what's the purpose of hiding namespaces if we can't access them?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that Dovecot doesn't create the virtual folders if it doesn't exist even with `auto = subscribe` is set.  It will show it if I create it from the command line. Which is a pain to do!

So if anyone can shed some light here, on any part of this (rather long) question, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are missing dovecot-virtual file. You have to provide instructions to Dovecot on how to select messages for your virtual folder in this special file. In your case, the correct location of this file is **probably** `~/Maildir/virtual."All mail".dovecot-virtual`.

The reason I am saying probably is that I am not sure that Dovecot and your file system will correctly handle the whitespace character in the path to this file. I would suggest starting with a name for your virtual folder that does not contain the whitespace character, for example: Allmail. Once everything is configured properly, you can change Allmail to "All mail" and see if the whitespace character breaks things or not.

The content of your dovecot-virtual file should be something like this:

```
*
  all
```

or if you want to exclude certain folders like Trash, Spam and Junk, you can use something like this:

```
*
-INBOX/Trash
-INBOX/Trash/*
-INBOX/Spam
-INBOX/Spam/*
-INBOX/Junk
-INBOX/Junk/*
  all
```

For more information on how to configure dovecot-virtual file and virtual folders generally, see the [Dovecot documentation](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/virtual_plugin/).